# Where we should change initial data in the serializer?

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

**Questions:**

Where I should change `initial_data` in the serializers?

Is it a recommended way to change `initial_data` in the `validate_field_name()` methods?

should `validate_field_name` methods return something?

**Code:**

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_owner(self, owner_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(owner_id=owner_id)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist or get_user_model().MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return owner_id
```

> If I don't change `initial_data` in `validate_field_name` methods, I'll fetch the data twice.

**For example:**

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_owner(self, owner_id):
        try:
            get_user_model().objects.get(owner_id=owner_id)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist or get_user_model().MultipleObjectsReturned:
            raise ValidationError('User does not exists.')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        validated_data['owner'] = get_user_model().objects.get(owner_id=validated_data['owner_id'])

        # create instance
```

Comment: not answering your question, 
but since it's a model-serializer, and assuming the `owner` field is a django `ForeignKey`, 

DRF should already do all of what you describe for you, should it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, absolutely yes , I just wrote it as an example.